# Highchart pie vertical legend align right not pinned to plot correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I can't indent legend from right plot border properly

[image]

My config

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie',
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: 1,
                        plotShadow: false,

                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            showInLegend: true,
                            center: [150, 150],
                        },
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'percent'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.2f}%)<br/>',
                        shared: true
                    },

                series: [{

                    name: "My plot",
                    type: 'pie',
                    innerSize: '70%',
                    data: [ ['item',4],['item2',50],['item3',8]]

                }],
                title: {
                    text: "My chart"
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth:1,

                },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69d1d22x/

I suppose that I need to align legend left and shift it to right but I did't find any hack.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to limit your chart **width** size?

Like :

```
(...)
type: 'pie',
plotBackgroundColor: null,
plotBorderWidth: 1,
plotShadow: false,
width: 450,
(...)
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/width/

Comment: Yes I tried. But it doesn't help a lot because I have to use maximum responsive block width. It will be nice to use percents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chart.marginRight` to give right margin to the plot. Use this code to position the legend next to it (the assumption here is that `legend.align` equals to `'right'`):

```
function alignLegend(chart) {
  var group = chart.legend.group;
  group.attr({
    translateX: chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth + chart.plotBox.x
  });
}
```

Place this function in `load` and `redraw` events.

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cthaLrb3/

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginRight
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

Comment: Thank u @KamilKulig! This works. Also I've tried this with angular 1.4.9 and hicharts-ng. Just need to define function in same scope as config e.g. in controller